# Can an incomplete steel shell contain a magnetostatic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

I have disassembled an electric motor, and have a question about
the static field of the two permanent magnets that are attached
opposite each other, inside the cylindrical steel housing.
They exert a fairly strong force on any piece of steel that I put
inside, but essentially no detectable force when the piece is outside
the housing, either radially or axially displaced from the cylinder.
Both ends of the cylinder are open.

This reminds me of what I think happens with an electric charge inside
a conductor cavity, but I'm not familiar with this in magnetism.

Can someone describe or give me a reference or a name for what is
happening here? Thanks.